# Parsing XML in Python with multiple tags

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to parse an XML file.
I succeeded at parsing tags at the upper layer, but now I have a tag within a tag and I'm not getting the correct output.

**XML FILE:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Stations>
    <Station>
    <Code>HT</Code>
    <Type>knooppuntIntercitystation</Type>
    <Namen>
    <Kort>Den Bosch</Kort>
    <Middel>'s-Hertogenbosch</Middel>
    <Lang>'s-Hertogenbosch</Lang>
    </Namen>
    <Land>NL</Land>
    <Synoniemen>
    <Synoniem>Hertogenbosch ('s)</Synoniem>
    <Synoniem>Den Bosch</Synoniem>
    </Synoniemen>
    </Station>
    <Station>
    <Code>ALMO</Code>
    <Type>stoptreinstation</Type>
    <Namen>
    <Kort>Oostvaard</Kort>
    <Middel>Oostvaarders</Middel>
    <Lang>Almere Oostvaarders</Lang>
    </Namen>
    <Land>NL</Land>
    <Synoniemen>
    </Synoniemen>
    </Station>
    <Station>
    <Code>ATN</Code>
    <Type>stoptreinstation</Type>
    <Namen>
    <Kort>Aalten</Kort>
    <Middel>Aalten</Middel>
    <Lang>Aalten</Lang>
    </Namen>
    <Land>NL</Land>
    <Synoniemen>
    </Synoniemen>
    </Station>
    <Station>
    <Code>ASA</Code>
    <Type>intercitystation</Type>
    <Namen>
    <Kort>Amstel</Kort>
    <Middel>Amsterdam Amstel</Middel>
    <Lang>Amsterdam Amstel</Lang>
    </Namen>
    <Land>NL</Land>
    <Synoniemen>
    </Synoniemen>
    </Station>
    </Stations>
```

**My python function:**

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree

e = xml.etree.ElementTree.parse('info.xml').getroot()

for stationsnamens in e.findall('Station'):
    try:
        syn = stationsnamens.find('Synoniemen/Synoniem').text
        print(syn)
    except:
        print(Exception)
```

I'm trying to print every `Synoniemen` field there is, but only if it exists. Also, the 'Code' needs to be printed.

**Output Format:**

```
{Code}: {Synoniemen}
```

Comment: I've read it, but it only says how to work with the upper layer. I can't find out how I can go Station/Synoniemen/Synoniem. If it would be just Synoniemen for example, I know how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like this (note: I have used `.fromstring()` in this example, but you can modify this for your own use with files)

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree
xmlstring = "<root><synoniemen><synoniem>A</synoniem><synoniem>B</synoniem></synoniemen></root>"
e = xml.etree.ElementTree.fromstring(xmlstring)
syn = e.find('synoniemen')
for synoniem in syn:
    print(synoniem.text)
```

point is that `syn` is a iterable  with a `for` as it contains multiple elements.

So your code will look something like this:

```
for stationsnamens in e.findall('Station'):
    code = stationsnames.find('Code')
    try:
        syn = stationsnamens.find('Synoniemen')
        for synoniem in syn:
            print(code.text, synoniem.text)
    except:
        print(Exception)
```

Comment: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable Is what I get

Comment: did you change from `syn = stationsnamens.find('Synoniemen/Synoniem').text` to `syn = stationsnamens.find('Synoniemen')` ??

Comment: Thank you, this is perfect. Do you also know how I can add the <Code> in front of the synoniem?

Comment: @SomeName, updated answer with 'Code'... if you want more, I advise you to 'play around with it' ... its what I did when I learned this (not too long ago) ... good luck :-)